# Howto disable Postgres listening on TCP?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, ubuntu, tcpip

Simply to avoid many problems in the first place I do not want my postgres server program to accept/listen to anything from any network (i.e. TCP/IP 4/6) connections.

My setup is a *Postgres 9.1* on an *Ubuntu 12.04* box and I thought tweeking `/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_hba.conf` to not include those lines which commented out (see below) would cause postgres to "please not listen on network TCP/IP devices"

```
local   all             postgres        trust

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
#local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
#host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
#host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

Also I know that there is the `-i` command line to start the postgres server with if we YES want to listen on TCP/IP . I actually seek for the opposite thing a `-???` meaning NO please do NOT listen on TCP/IP.

I used a `netstat -utap | grep post`  and it shows that postgres besides my settings in `/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_hba.conf` is still listening on  TCP/IP.

### QUESTION

What did I do wrong here? How can I shut off this TCP/IP listening attitude of my Postgres server?
Having only unix socket listening I am happy to the max ;)

Thank you

Addition: I also perceive that postgres establishes a **UDP** connection to this `127.0.0.1:38860`, what would this be about?

Answer (score 7):

Maybe it is not the finest *Solution* / *Answer* to my question, but at least it will point anybody (facing the said challenge I had in my original question)

To disable listening on TCP/IP network I used this command line option when starting the server application:

`postgres [other arguments] -c listen_addresses=''`

Addition:
The remaining open udp `127.0.0.1:38860` connection is supposedly linked to the 
purpose of the *the statistics collector subprocess* as suggested on [postgresql.org](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/21283.1008989228@sss.pgh.pa.us)

Comment: `listen_addresses` is specified in `postgresql.conf` along the other server parameters. You may change it here rather than on the command line

Comment: @DanielVérité Your suggested is noted and correct. I think the command line form can help you **override / overwrite** the `postgresql.conf` setting in case of need (i.e. you cannot change it for file permissions).

Comment: @DanielVérité Can you maybe confirm that `listen_addresses`needs explicitly and necessarily been set to `''` to provoke "No TCP/IP Listening"? I actually thought that having `pq_hba.conf` without `host`entries was already sufficient, which anyway I did *not* observe (even without `host` lines in `pq_hba.conf` it still listened at TCP/IP). Thank you!

Comment: Yes, `listen_addresses` must be used, and postgres does not guess the interfaces to listen to based on the rules in `pg_hba.conf`. Besides, to change `listen_addresses` a full restart of the server is necessary, whereas a simple reload is needed for a change in `pg_hba.conf` (the latter being harmless for established connections).

Comment: @DanielVérité Thank you for your help and confirmation. I was misled by the address column in `pg_hba.conf` thinking this was powerful enough to indicate to the server where to listen and where not. Thanks to you I know am aware that setting `listen_addresses=''` empty is the right way to go :)

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer;

Change the listen_addresses configuration setting
Here is an example;

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET listen_addresses TO '';
```

Then restart the Postgresql service

[Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-connection.html) says

> If the list is empty, the server does not listen on any IP interface
> at all, in which case only Unix-domain sockets can be used to connect
> to it.

Comment: In modern postgres'es it is listen_addresses instead of listen_adress

Comment: @JürgenWeigert I updated the answer

Comment: `ALTER: command not found` am I using the right program `postgres`??

Comment: @Soren AFAIK it's available after version 9.4. It's an SQL statement. User must be superuser.

Comment: It has to be used with psql for example: `sudo -u postgres psql -c "ALTER SYSTEM SET listen_addresses TO '*'"`

Comment: psql is just a client tool. you can use any other client to execute sql