# listen_addresses does not respect postgresql.conf

Tags: postgresql

I have PostgreSQL 9.3, and I'm trying to set it up on CentOS. One part that has been driving me nuts is the `listen_addresses` setting.

I set it to `*` inside `postgresql.conf`:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

but when I look inside `psql`, I see it as `localhost`:

```
postgres=# show listen_addresses;
listen_addresses
-----------------
 localhost
(1 row)
```

I do restart the postgresql instance after changing `postgresql.conf`. Also, `show config_file` verifies that I'm changing the right `postgresql.conf` file. Moreover, I run `ps aux | grep postgres` and make sure that there are no rogue command line parameters (like `-i` or `-c`) but only `-D` to set up the data directory.

When I do `select name,source,sourcefile,sourceline,setting from pg_settings where name like  '%listen%';` I see that `source` is `default`, `sourcefile` and `sourceline` are empty for `listen_addresses` (the `setting` is, as I said above, `localhost`)

When I do `netstat -na | grep 15432` (`15432` is my PostgreSQL port, I set it up inside `postgresql.conf` and also as an environment variable `PGPORT`), I see something like following:

```
tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:15432 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN
```

I think if `listen_addresses` were `*` I'd have `0:0:0:0:15432` rather than `127.0.0.1:15432`

So, how can I solve this problem?

Relevant questions:

[listen_addresses set to '*' in postgresql.conf disappears every reboot of Ubuntu](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/68204/listen-addresses-set-to-in-postgresql-conf-disappears-every-reboot-of-ubuntu)

[Howto disable Postgres listening on TCP?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52306/howto-disable-postgres-listening-on-tcp)

http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/pg-ctl-stop-failure-td5755968.html

[How to connect to an remote PostgreSQL database on Ubuntu using pgAdmin3?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18717/how-to-connect-to-an-remote-postgresql-database-on-ubuntu-using-pgadmin3)

**Edit 1** When I start postgres with `-i` option and do `show listen_addresses;`, I do see `*`.

Comment: You did remove the comment character at the start of the line? Just checking!

Comment: Yes, I did remove the # =)

Comment: Is it possible that you have another listen_address line in this file? It might be overriding your setting

Comment: Are you sure `ps aux` is showing you all, and not just the first so many characters?  Also, look for a systemd config file.  Or just build your own postgres from scratch, then you won't have to fight the packagers decisions.